# How to blur an image after obtaining its mask using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've followed a guide on blurring image based on colour segmentation: https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/

But I have trouble in getting it to blur only the nemo in the original image.

What I have so far from following the guide:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

nemo = cv2.imread('nemo.png')
nemo = cv2.cvtColor(nemo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
hsv_nemo = cv2.cvtColor(nemo, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

light_orange = (1, 190, 200)
dark_orange = (18, 255, 255)
light_white = (0, 0, 200)
dark_white = (145, 60, 255)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_nemo, light_orange, dark_orange)
mask_white = cv2.inRange(hsv_nemo, light_white, dark_white)
final_mask = mask + mask_white

final_result = cv2.bitwise_and(nemo, nemo, mask=final_mask)
blur = cv2.blur(final_result, (15, 15), 0)
```

I've plotted out 1) `nemo`, 2) `final_mask`, and 3) `blur` for comparison here: [Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZieH.png)

Is there a way for me to blur the nemo in the original photo such that it looks something like this: [Blurred Original Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgbQw.png)

At the moment it only blurs nemo in the mask image.

I think I need to obtain a ROI for me to do so, but how do I form the relationship between a mask and getting the coordinates/ ROI of the nemo from the original photo? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about opencv, but why do you need the mask if you want to blur the original picture? Also, I guess with `cv2.bitwise_and` all parts that are black in one of the arguments will be black in the result, and since the mask is black everywhere except for the fish, the resulting image will also be black everywhere except for the fish.

Comment: My assumption is only nemo needs to be blurred, in which case replace the original imaged with the blurred image where mask is True e.g. `np.where(mask, blurred, original)`

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle I was thinking with the mask, I will be able to make use of that information to help locate the roi / coordinates of the fish in the original photo? so i can blur only specific parts of the original image.. correct me if i'm wrong, i am very new to opencv too!

Comment: I didn't understand that you only want to blur the fish of the original image. As already said, I don't really know opencv, but Julien's solution sounds good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to blur the image only where the mask is true, something like this should work

```
blur = cv2.blur(nemo,(15,15),0)
out = nemo.copy()
out[mask>0] = blur[mask>0]
```

However, you may want to change how the mask has been generated, as currently it will only blur the orange and white parts of the fish.

Comment: But blur will use outside of the mask data on the edges during evaluation. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that works on a Vec3b but only looks at channel 0.
It respects the mask and only blurs where there is not a mask. This prevents "halo" effects on the edges of interior masked areas. In my case it is a ball with the outside of circle masked out and also the glare spot reflected off the ball.

```
    void MyPipelineCPU::MyBlur(Mat& src, Mat& mask, Mat& dst, const int diameter) {
    if (dst.empty() || dst.rows != src.rows || dst.cols != src.cols || dst.type() != src.type())
        dst = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, src.type());

    const int diamter2 = diameter * diameter;
    const int radius = diameter / 2;
    const int radius2 = radius * radius;
    const int rowmax = src.rows - radius;
    const int colmax = src.cols - radius;
    for (int r = radius; r < rowmax; r++) {
        for (int c = radius; c < colmax; c++) {
            uchar msk = mask.at<uchar>(r, c);
            if (msk) {
                Vec3b& srcP = src.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
                Vec3b& dstP = dst.at<Vec3b>(r, c);

                // It is treated as a grey image even though three channels
                int sum0 = 0;
                int count0 = 0;
                for (int dy = -radius; dy <= radius; dy++) {
                    for (int dx = -radius; dx <= radius; dx++) {
                        if (mask.at<uchar>(r + dy, c + dx)) {
                            const Vec3b& pp = src.at<Vec3b>(r + dy, c + dx);
                            sum0 += pp[0];
                            count0++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (count0 > 4) {
                    const int avg0 = sum0 / count0;
                    // Blur
                    dstP[0] = avg0;
                    dstP[1] = avg0;
                    dstP[2] = avg0;
                }
                else {
                    dstP[0] = 0;
                    dstP[1] = 0;
                    dstP[2] = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                Vec3b& dstP = dst.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
                dstP[0] = 0;
                dstP[1] = 0;
                dstP[2] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```